# VSCode Rails debugging does not hit breakpoint visually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, debugging

When debugging a rails application in VSCode it hits the breakpoint in the debug console but not in VSCode itself (I think). The rails application becomes unresponsive because it is stuck. Also when adding/deleting a breakpoin, the debugger sometimes crashes.

I followed this blog: https://dev.to/abstractart/easy-way-to-setup-debugger-and-autocomplete-for-ruby-in-visual-studio-code-2gcc

launch.json:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Start rails server",
      "type": "Ruby",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/rails",
      "useBundler": true,
      "pathToBundler": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/bundle",
      "showDebuggerOutput": true,
      "pathToRDebugIDE": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/rdebug-ide",
      "args": ["s"]
    }
  ]
}
```

gemfile:

```
  ruby "3.2.0"
  ...
  gem "ruby-debug-ide", "~> 0.7.3"
  gem "debase", "~> 0.2.5.beta2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, make sure to set `WEB_CONCURRENCY` to zero!